# Apply userdir to the APACHE_MODULES in OpenSuse 12.1

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, opensuse, yast

i am running opensuse 12.1

i have installed apache2 and all lampp-things via YAST. But i am not sure if all is done now!?

```
linux-r4qe:/home/martin # apache2ctl -M |grep userdir
httpd2: Syntax error on line 188 of /etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/sysconfig.d/include.conf: No such file or directory
linux-r4qe:/home/martin #
```

well i have to do the installation according this advice!:

If userdir is not installed then do a check  via YaST /etc/sysconfig editor and add userdir to the modules APACHE_MODULES section.

How should i do that: do i have to do this via YAST

**Question:** Should i do a search for the usedir !? and afterwards install it!?
additional: Does it find "its way" to the APACHE_MODULES-Section

Can i install this via a certain command - this might be easier...

And finally: Do i have to any further configurations - to make the Apache2 running!?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use yast. It is also possible to edit all the things you need manually. Manual configuration without using yast at all gives you the power of more detailed configuration but also sometimes lacks the convenience of the yast GUI and cause problems when you use both. Once you considered using one method it is highly recommended to not mix up both methods of configuring the apache2 webserver.

The configuration for *mod_userdir* in opensuse is done in **/etc/apache2/mod_userdir.conf**

Also **/etc/sysconfig/apache2** controls some global settings. These can either be edited using `yast --> System --> Editor for /etc/sysconfig`

[image]

or you could edit this file with your favorite editor like vim or whatever editor you prefer. These files in opensuse are pretty well documented.

Also you should read the documentation which is available [here](http://doc.opensuse.org/) or use zypper to install it for offline viewing:

```
zypper in opensuse-manuals_en
```

i hope i could help you. If you have more questions on this topic you could join us in #opensuse in  the irc channel on freenode.net and get more help there.

Comment: great to hear from you - i try itout